# How to make a resizable circle in google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code, the circle is already moveable, now I want it to be resizeable:

```
  function init() {
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      'zoom': 1,
      'center': mapCenter,
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(55, 0),
      draggable: true,
      title: 'Drag me!'
    });

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 3000000 // 3000 km
    });

    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
  }

  // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Now, how can I do the resizer? I already read: http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html
But there isn't another way to do that?

Answer (score 8):

The `google.maps.Circle` object has method `.setEditable(true)`. The description from the docs says:

> If set to true, the user can edit this circle by dragging the control
>   points shown at the center and around the circumference of the circle.